# ArcGIS Arcade Pop-Up Record Concatenate

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have numerous records where FieldName1 = categories, and FieldName2 = unique types. I am trying to concatenate FieldName2 by FieldName1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Arcade expression for your pop-up configuration:

```
$feature.FieldName1 + ", " + $feature.FieldName2
```

This expression will concatenate the values from FieldName1 and FieldName2 with a comma and a space in between. You can replace the `,`  with any other separator that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Although a previous answer would work, I suggest using [Concatenate | Text functions | ArcGIS Arcade | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#concatenate) since it provides additional functionality for formatting characters for dates and numbers.

```js
Concatenate([$feature.FieldName1 , $feature.FieldName2 ], ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistyped my original question.

I want the items to be unique by Field 1. I did find a solution:

```
var fc = $layer
var orderRA = OrderBy(fc, "Determination")
var arr = ''
for(var x in orderRA) {
    if(x.Determination=='Compatible') {
        arr += concatenate(x.Land_Use, ', ')
 }
 }
 return Distinct(Split(arr, ', '));
```